# Python exception headlining from specific module

Tags: python

I have a module that I'm using that has its own exceptions.  Is there a way of catching all the exceptions from that module without explicitly spelling out the exceptions?

So let's say I have a module named `foo` and it has errors `foo.a` `foo.b` ... `foo.z`
How would I do something like

```
try:
    method_from_foo() # throws a foo error
except any_foo_exception: # Can be any exception from the module foo
                          # if foo.a is thrown then it's caught here
                          # if foo.anything is thrown then it's caught here
    pass
```

instead of doing

```
try:
    method_from_foo() # throws a foo error
except foo.a, foo.b, ... foo.z:
    pass
```

I don't want to do a blanket `Except` as I want to catch all other exceptions not related to `foo`

Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way you usually do this by having a base type for all your exceptions that are related to your module. So if you have a `FancyFooBar` module, you might want to create a `FancyFooBarException` first:

```
class FancyFooBarException (Exeption):
    pass
```

And then you can crete your exceptions `A`, `B`, …, and base them off that:

```
class AException (FancyFooBarException):
    pass

class BException (FancyFooBarException):
    pass

# ...
```

That way, all your exceptions that are thrown are of the same type, FancyFooBarException, but still hold a more specific type for a more special differentiation. So you can do this:

```
try:
    fancyfoobar.someMethod()
except fancyfoobar.AException:
    print('AException!')
except fancyfoobar.FancyFooBarException:
    print('One of the other exceptions')
except Exception:
    Print('Any other exception.. we do not really want to catch this though')
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I'm looking for a way of not spelling out every error that inherits `FancyFooBarException`.  I don't care about the errors it throws I just want to know that it came from the `foo` module regardless of the specific error.

Comment: Well, yeah, that’s my point. In my example `someMethod` may throw `BException` or `CException` but I’m not catching it explicitely; instead, I’m just catching `FancyFooBarException` which is the base type of those exceptions. And by doing that, I get all the exceptions that are subtypes of that one too. And in case, I still want to handle a single exception differently (in my example AException`), I can do that as long as I catch it *before* the base exception.

Comment: Oh I see.  Sorry for the confusion. Thanks!

Comment: Ah! I see poke beat me to the punch with an even better answer. But yes, Jeff, this is how you want to do your exceptions. If you don't care about the individual errors, just test for the parent class.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a single parent exception for foo, and have all your other exceptions inherit from it. Then, in your try statement, test for the parent class:

```
In [126]: class parentException(Exception):
   .....:     def __init__(self):
   .....:         self.value = "Parent Exception"
   .....:     def __str__(self):
   .....:         return repr(self.value)
   .....:     

In [127]: class child1Exception(parentException):
   .....:     def __init__(self):
   .....:         self.value = "Child 1 Exception"
   .....:         

In [128]: class child2Exception(parentException):
   .....:     def __init__(self):
   .....:         self.value = "Child 2 Exception"
   .....:             

In [129]: try:
   .....:     raise child1Exception
   .....: except parentError:
   .....:     print "Caught child1"
   .....:     
Caught child1
```